# How can I move parent & child tables data to archive tables (which has same columns)

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, oracle, hsqldb

Suppose I have parent table : Transaction_Logger

```
--------------------------------------------
Id     | Txn_Name   | Txn_Status  | Txn_Time
--------------------------------------------
101    | C2C        | Executed    | 11-july-17
--------------------------------------------
201    | B2B        | Aborted     | 11-July-17
--------------------------------------------
301    | B2C        | Executed    | 12-July-17
```

And child table: Transaction_Error (Txn_Id is foreign key with Transaction_Logger table ID column)

```
 ------------------------------------
    Id     | Error_msg     | Txn_Id 
 ------------------------------------
    410    | some error msg| 201   
 ------------------------------------
```

I also have another 2 tables with same structure Transaction_Logger_Archive & Transaction_Error_Archive respectively.

we need to archive main tables data to archive tables. Is there any pre-define way that if we move parent table (Transaction_Logger) data to its archive table (Transaction_Logger_Archive) then child table (Transaction_Error) data automatically get archive to its archive table (Transaction_Error_Archive)? 
For example : We have deleteOnCascade that deletes child table record on delete of parent table record.

I need to support above behaviour on database servers: MySql, SqlServer, Oracle & Hsql

Comment: Have you tried using triggers on your DB?
Also, why do you use `java`tag within this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use of the [**MySQL Event Scheduler**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events.html). This is a built in event scheduler in MySQL.

You can specify it to call a procedure at designated intervals.

Read the MySQL docs but an example would be:

```
CREATE EVENT yourdatabase.eventname
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
 CALL YOURPROCEDURE();
```

And in YOURPROCEDURE you can wrote logic for archive your multiple table.

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE YOURPROCEDURE()
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE CURRENT_DATE_VAR DATETIME;
/*
Your stuff
*/
END$

DELIMITER ;
```

Event Scheduler is by default disable in MySQL. You can turn it on run:

**`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`**